# Exhibiting triviality in the Brauer group

Tags: abstract-algebra

The starting place for this question lies in the following construction: given a field $F$ containing a primitive $n$th root of unity $\omega$ and two elements $\alpha, \beta \in F^{\times}$, we produce the noncommutative algebra

$$A_{\omega}(\alpha, \beta) := F<x, y>/<x^n = \alpha, y^n = \beta, xy = \omega yx>$$

it can be shown that this $F$-algebra is simple, central (i.e. the center is just $F$) and finite dimensional over $F$ - in particular, $\{x^iy^j\}_{0 \leq i, j < n}$ give a basis - and thus defines an element in the Brauer group $Br(F)$. (See Milnor's *Introduction to Algebraic K-theory*, the chapter on the power norm residue symbol).

Now, for a specific choice of $F$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ coming from something else, I can deduce that $A_{\omega}(\alpha, \beta)^{\otimes 2}$ is trivial in the Brauer group - and thus, by dimension counting, must be isomorphic to $Mat(n^2, F)$. This leads me to my question:

*Is there a way to write down an isomorphism?*

(Notation: From this point on, as we only care about $A_\omega(\alpha, \beta)^{\otimes 2}$, let us define $B := A_{\omega}(\alpha, \beta)^{\otimes 2}$)

I have a proposed method: fixing any right $B$-submodule $M$ of $B$ (just a right ideal of $B$), let $B' = End_B(M)$ and $B'' = End_{B'}(M)$. There is a natural map

$$\phi: B \to B''$$
$$b \to \phi(b)(m) = m.b$$

Using $B$ is simple, we get that $\phi$ is an isomorphism (compare Theorem 3.1 in http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/brauer.pdf). If in addition we chose $M$ to be simple, $B'$ must be some division ring $D$ over $F$ by Schur's Lemma. As $M$ is a finitely generated $D$-module, it must just be $D^k$ for some $k$. Thus,

$$B = End_D(D^k) = Mat(k, D)$$

That $B$ is trivial in $Br(F)$ tells us that $D = F$. Dimension arguments give that $M$ must have dimension $n^2$ over $F$. If an $M$ could be given with a basis over $F$ such that the action of any element of $b$ on $M$ by right multiplication could be readily expressed in terms of this basis, then we would be able to give a concrete isomorphism $B \cong Mat(n^2, F)$

*Punchline: We need to find a right ideal $M \subset B$ of dimension $n^2$*

And here is where I'm hopelessly stuck. I feel like there should be an apparent $M$ screaming out, especially because of the explicitly constructed nature of $B$, but I just can't see it! If you've made it this far, thanks for reading, and please let me know any thoughts you have!